# Form select is showing entire row not one column

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to make a filter for my table but i see a problem there. Maybe the problem is from table structure couse i fetch all structure as it is on mysql. Does anyone help to make this filter in right way.
The `collapse content` under comment  is the head i display when i want to filter

```
<table class="table table-hover align-middle mb-0">
                    <thead class="">
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="selectAll" title="Select All"></th>
                            <th v-if="!isHidden[index]" v-for="(header, index) in visibleHeaders" :key="index" scope="col">
                                {{ header }}
                            </th>
                            <th>ACTION</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!-- Collapsed content ./ -->
                    <thead class="collapse" id="collapseFilter">
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th v-for="(header, index) in visibleHeaders" scope="col">
                                <select  id="" class="form-select" >
                                    <option v-for="column in leads">
                                        <div v-for="(atr, key, index) in column">
                                            {{atr}}
                                        </div>
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!-- ./ Collapse contet -->
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-show="leads.length" v-for="column in leads" >
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="selected" :value="column.id" />
                            </td>
                            <td v-if="!isHidden[index]" v-for="(atr, key, index) in column">
                                <div v-if="atr == 'new'">
                                    <span class="badge bg-info">{{ atr }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div v-else-if="atr == 'contract'">
                                    <span class="badge bg-success">{{ atr }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>
                                    <span >{{ atr }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button @click="editLead(column.id)" type="button" class="btn  btn-sm btn-secondary"  data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#editLeadModal" >
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr v-show="!leads.length">
                            <td colspan="12" class="text-center">Sorry :( No data found.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

[image]

If i try to loop only `v-for="column in lead"`
[image]

Comment: *"but i see a problem there"* - well what is the problem? Please describe.

Comment: The problem is one option show entire row when clicked. I want to show only option for specific column. I just add a screenshot of the filter

Comment: In your `v-for="column in leads"` loop you also output all of them: `v-for="(atr, key, index) in column`.

Comment: You mean to use double `v-for` in same `td`?

Comment: I think its not possible to use double `v-for` so  i suspect you are trying to tell me i need to remove `v-for="(atr, key, index) in column` from `div` when i call loop. But if i do this i can see an array with all row data.

Comment: Yes I mean you only want to show one column as you wrote, so why have a loop that renders all of them every time? You just want to render the one option.

Comment: Then i will add new screenshot on my question to see whats hapend if i try to loop only `v-for="column in lead"

Comment: You don't have to document everything that goes wrong with screenshots. Just access the field you want to access.

Comment: This is the problem. I dont know how to do

Comment: Ok that works just how you do in in JavaScript. You can just access an object property with `.` and then its name. So for example `column.first_name` or `column['first_name']`. You can use the Vue Developer tools to see a component's values.

Comment: I know this method but it work only when table fiels ex: `first_name` is static, i have each field called from db and i cant use hardcode to display specidic field couse they need to change sometime and there is why i use dynamically field

Comment: Okay then rename the `index` from your inner loop. You can use the `index` from visibleHeaders and use the inner index to find out which one you should display.

Comment: This return empty value to me

Comment: We can't have a week long discussion here. I suggest you install [Vue Developer Tools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) so you can look at the values in the browser console.